# MySQL - Restore DB from backup file but also keep newer records

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I perform a full MySQL db backup twice a day creating a MySQL dump file.
Some records were accidentally deleted but when I realized the missing data, several more records had been added.

What's the best way to restore the missing data without losing the newer data as well? Maybe by replacing the INSERT with REPLACE in the dump file? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `REPLACE` is the best solution according to minimum efforts and clear work.